# Unique custom sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I have a different kind of sorting requirement. Suppose if I select 3 columns anyhow for ascending sorting, then the 1st column should sort normally in ascending order, but the next column should sort in ascending order without changing the order of 1st column as it was sorted first, and same for the 3rd column that it will not change the order of 1st and 2nd column. 
for eg,

initially withut sorted:

9  b  y
9  c  a
1  a  z

after sorting 1st column:

1  a  z
9  b  y
9  c  a

on sorting 3rd column it should be like thi not affecting 1st colum:

1  a  z
9  b  y
9  c  a

Comment: post the server-side code that is building data

Comment: this sorting will be done in client side.. server will give the data through ajax call in json format.

Comment: since version 4.5 jqgrid supports multisorting, you can check the [demo](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx)

Comment: but here it is different from multi sorting..i have to fix some column and sort other columns..

Comment: this is exactly what jqgrid multisorting does!